# How can I find the most common starting letter in a list?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and this question might be tedious.
Lets's say I have a `list=['stack',....,'overflow']` with `len(list)=n`. I want to find the most common starting letter in the list. i.e 'i'. I tried to use `.startswith()` and `.most_common([n])` but I didn't get the result. What would be a good approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
Counter(x[0] for x in lst).most_common()[0]
```

where `lst` is your list. (*Note that I have renamed your list to `lst`*)

**Example**:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['stack', 'in', 'over', 'for', 'overflow'] 

print(Counter(x[0] for x in lst).most_common()[0])
# ('o', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use implementation below. I have explained all steps in comments.

```
words = ["a","b","a","d","d"] # it is your list

frequencies = [(letter, words.count(letter)) for letter in set(words)] #we are taking letters and their counts which is a tuple in a list
most_frequent_letter = sorted(frequencies, key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[0] # and we are doing a stable sort for listing most frequent letters first.

print(most_frequent_letter)
```